# Best design for Java Parsing several CSV files with different headers and model objects

Tags: java, parsing, design-patterns, abstract-class, factory

I have several CSV files that I will need to Parse. and use later for Insert in MYSQL. I have already written one parser but I want to avoid as much as I can code duplication

I have already in mind that I should use an abstract class, or maybe a Factory but I can't really put a finger on the best way to design this.

So this is my parser :

```
public class LocusAliasCsvParser {

private static final String[] FILE_HEADER_MAPPING = {"id", "locusID", "organismid", "variable", "alias"};

private static final String ID = "id";
private static final String LOCUS_ID = "locusID";
private static final String ORGANISM_ID = "organismid";
private static final String VARIABLE = "variable";
private static final String ALIAS = "alias";


public static List<AliasLocus> readCsvFile(String fileName) {

    FileReader fileReader = null;
    CSVParser csvFileParser = null;

    CSVFormat csvFileFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader(FILE_HEADER_MAPPING);
    List<AliasLocus> aliases = new ArrayList();

    try {
        fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
        csvFileParser = new CSVParser(fileReader, csvFileFormat);

        //Get a list of CSV file records
        List csvRecords = csvFileParser.getRecords();

        //Read the CSV file. Header is ignored (i == 1)
        for (int i = 1; i < csvRecords.size(); i++) {
            CSVRecord record = (CSVRecord) csvRecords.get(i);

            AliasLocus aliasLocus = new AliasLocus(Integer.parseInt(record.get(ID)),
                    record.get(LOCUS_ID),
                    record.get(ORGANISM_ID),
                    record.get(VARIABLE),
                    record.get(ALIAS));

            aliases.add(aliasLocus);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error in CsvFileReader !!!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            fileReader.close();
            csvFileParser.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error while closing fileReader/csvFileParser !!!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return aliases;
}
```

The things that change each time are :

```
public class LocusAliasCsvParser {

private static final String[] FILE_HEADER_MAPPING = {"id", "locusID", "organismid", "variable", "alias"};

private static final String ID = "id";
private static final String LOCUS_ID = "locusID";
private static final String ORGANISM_ID = "organismid";
private static final String VARIABLE = "variable";
private static final String ALIAS = "alias";
```

and :

```
 public static List<AliasLocus> readCsvFile(String fileName) {

 AliasLocus aliasLocus = new AliasLocus(Integer.parseInt(record.get(ID)),
                    record.get(LOCUS_ID),
                    record.get(ORGANISM_ID),
                    record.get(VARIABLE),
                    record.get(ALIAS));
```

does anyone can suggest the best design patters or structure to use to have the least code duplication?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should separate the different concerns using interfaces and implement a template method for reading csv files.

Let's setup a simple framework in 6 steps.

1. You need a class that knows how to obtain the structure of the csv.

   ```
   public interface CsvMetadataSource {
        public CsvMetadata getCsvMetadata();
   }
   ```
2. You will need a class that can parse a csv line. The `CsvMetadata` from 1. is a good place to put that logic into.

   ```
   public class CsvMetadata {

       private List<String> columns;

       public CsvMetadata(List<String> columns) {
           this.columns = columns;
       }

       public Map<String, String> parseLine(String line) {
           // simple implementation 
           String[] values = line.split(",");

           Map<String, String> record = new HashMap<>();

           for (int i = 0; i < columns.size(); i++) {
               String column = columns.get(i);

               String value = null;

               if (i < values.length) {
                   value = values[i];
               }

               record.put(column, value);
           }

           return record;
       }

   }
   ```
3. You need a class that can map a parsed line into an object. Knowing the line number might also be useful.

   ```
   public interface CsvRecordMapper<T> {
       public T map(Map<String, String> csvRecord, int lineNumber);
   }
   ```
4. You need a class that knows what to do with the mapped objects.

   ```
   public interface CsvObjectCallback<T> {
       public void process(T object);
   }
   ```
5. You need a class that implements the template method for reading csv data and that can be extended by implementations of the interfaces above. It might also be good to have a convenience method for reading all objects as list.

   ```
   public class CsvReader {

       private CsvMetadataSource csvMetadataSource = null;

       public CsvReader() {
       }

       public CsvReader(CsvMetadataSource csvMetadataSource) {
           this.csvMetadataSource = csvMetadataSource;
       }

       public <T> List<T> readAll(Reader csvInputReader, CsvRecordMapper<T> csvLineMapper) throws IOException {
           CollectCsvObjectCallback<T> collectCsvObjectCallback = new CollectCsvObjectCallback<>();
           read(csvInputReader, csvLineMapper, collectCsvObjectCallback);
           return collectCsvObjectCallback.getObjects();
       }

       public <T> void read(Reader csvInputReader, CsvRecordMapper<T> csvLineMapper,
               CsvObjectCallback<T> csvObjectCallback) throws IOException {
           try (BufferedReader lineReader = new BufferedReader(csvInputReader);) {
               CsvMetadataSource effectiveCsvMetadataSource = getCsvMetadataSource(lineReader);

               read(csvLineMapper, csvObjectCallback, lineReader, effectiveCsvMetadataSource);
           }
       }

       private CsvMetadataSource getCsvMetadataSource(BufferedReader lineReader) throws IOException {
           CsvMetadataSource effectiveCsvMetadataSource = csvMetadataSource;
           if (effectiveCsvMetadataSource == null) {
               String headerLine = lineReader.readLine();
               effectiveCsvMetadataSource = new RowBasedCsvMetadataSource(headerLine);
           }
           return effectiveCsvMetadataSource;
       }

       private <T> void read(CsvRecordMapper<T> csvLineMapper, CsvObjectCallback<T> csvObjectCallback,
               BufferedReader lineReader, CsvMetadataSource effectiveCsvMetadataSource) throws IOException {
           CsvMetadata effectiveCsvMetadata = effectiveCsvMetadataSource.getCsvMetadata();
           if (effectiveCsvMetadata != null) {
               String line;
               int csvRecordNumber = 0;

               while ((line = lineReader.readLine()) != null) {
                   Map<String, String> csvRecordValues = effectiveCsvMetadata.parseLine(line);
                   T object = csvLineMapper.map(csvRecordValues, csvRecordNumber++);
                   csvObjectCallback.process(object);
               }
           }
       }

   }

   class RowBasedCsvMetadataSource implements CsvMetadataSource {

       private String row;

       public RowBasedCsvMetadataSource(String row) {
           this.row = row;
       }

       @Override
       public CsvMetadata getCsvMetadata() {
           String[] columns = row.split(",");
           return new CsvMetadata(Arrays.asList(columns));
       }

   }

   class CollectCsvObjectCallback<T> implements CsvObjectCallback<T> {

       private List<T> objects = new ArrayList<>();

       @Override
       public void process(T object) {
           objects.add(object);
       }

       public List<T> getObjects() {
           return objects;
       }

   }
   ```
6. Finally you can easily adapt new csv file formats by implementing just a `CsvRecordMapper`. E.g.

   ```
   public class UserCsvRecordMapper implements CsvRecordMapper<User> {

       public User map(Map<String, String> csvRecord, int lineNumber) {
           String firstname = csvRecord.get("FIRST NAME");
           String lastname = csvRecord.get("LAST NAME");
           String username = csvRecord.get("USERNAME");
           String email = csvRecord.get("EMAIL ADDRESS");

           return new User(firstname, lastname, username, email);
       }
   }

   public class User {

       private String firstname;
       private String lastname;
       private String username;
       private String email;

       public User(String firstname, String lastname, String username, String email) {
           this.firstname = firstname;
           this.lastname = lastname;
           this.username = username;
           this.email = email;
       }

       public String getFirstname() {
           return firstname;
       }

       public String getLastname() {
           return lastname;
       }

       public String getUsername() {
           return username;
       }

       public String getEmail() {
           return email;
       }

       @Override
       public String toString() {
           return "User [firstname=" + firstname + ", lastname=" + lastname + ", username=" + username + ", email=" + email
                   + "]";
       }

   }
   ```

From a client's perspective it is easy to use.

CSV

```
FIRST NAME,LAST NAME,USERNAME,PASSWORD,EMAIL ADDRESS,PHONE NUMBER,PASSPORT,GROUPS,USERCODE,TITLE,ADDRESS 1 ,ADDRESS 2,CITY,STATE,ZIP
Frank,Riley,friley,changeme,friley@kanab.org,123-456-7890,3,"1,3",1040,Teacher,328 Innovation,Suite # 200 ,state college,PA,16803
Steve,Brannigan,sbrannigan,changeme,sbrannigan@kanab.org,123-456-7890,3,1,1041,Teacher,328 Innovation,Suite # 200 ,state college,PA,16803
Marie,Ambrose,mambrose,changeme,mambrose@kanab.org,123-456-7890,3,1,1042,Teacher,328 Innovation,Suite # 200 ,state college,PA,16803
```

And a simple main class

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputStream csvInputStream = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("example.csv");
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(csvInputStream);

        CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader();
        List<User> users = csvReader.readAll(inputStreamReader, new UserCsvRecordMapper());

        for (User user : users) {
            System.out.println(user);
        }

    }
}
```

The result is

```
User [firstname=Frank, lastname=Riley, username=friley, email=friley@kanab.org]
User [firstname=Steve, lastname=Brannigan, username=sbrannigan, email=sbrannigan@kanab.org]
User [firstname=Marie, lastname=Ambrose, username=mambrose, email=mambrose@kanab.org]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my pretty straitforward solution.

Declare converters from CSVRecord to each desired entity:

```
class AliasLocusMapper { 
    public static final String[] FILE_HEADER_MAPPING = {"id", "locusID", "organismid", "variable", "alias"};

    private static final String ID = "id";
    private static final String LOCUS_ID = "locusID";
    private static final String ORGANISM_ID = "organismid";
    private static final String VARIABLE = "variable";
    private static final String ALIAS = "alias";

    public static AliasLocus mapRecord(CSVRecord record) {
        return new AliasLocus(Integer.parseInt(record.get(ID)),
                record.get(LOCUS_ID),
                record.get(ORGANISM_ID),
                record.get(VARIABLE),
                record.get(ALIAS));
    }
}

class ProductMapper { // Product is an example class
    public static final String[] FILE_HEADER_MAPPING = {"id", "title", "price"};

    private static final String ID = "id";
    private static final String TITLE = "title";
    private static final String PRICE = "price";

    public static Product mapRecord(CSVRecord record) {
        return new Product(Integer.parseInt(record.get(ID)),
                record.get(TITLE),
                record.get(PRICE));
    }
}
```

Then make Parser more universal

```
public class AbstractCsvParser {

    public <T> List<T> readCsvFile(String fileName, String[] headers, Function<CSVRecord, T> mapper) {

        FileReader fileReader = null;
        CSVParser csvFileParser = null;

        CSVFormat csvFileFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader(headers);
        List<T> entities = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
            csvFileParser = new CSVParser(fileReader, csvFileFormat);

            //Get a list of CSV file records
            List csvRecords = csvFileParser.getRecords();

            //Read the CSV file. Header is ignored (i == 1)
            for (int i = 1; i < csvRecords.size(); i++) {
                CSVRecord record = (CSVRecord) csvRecords.get(i);

                T result = mapper.apply(record); // transform to desired enitity

                entities.add(result);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // omitted
        }

        return entities;
    }
}
```

And then use in following way

```
    AbstractCsvParser parser = new AbstractCsvParser();

    List<AliasLocus> aliases = parser.readCsvFile(
            "aliases.csv",
            AliasLocusMapper.FILE_HEADER_MAPPING,
            AliasLocusMapper::mapRecord);

    List<Product> products = parser.readCsvFile(
            "products.csv",
            ProductMapper.FILE_HEADER_MAPPING,
            ProductMapper::mapRecord);
```